# What does Docker use to host/run web applications?

Tags: docker, web, hosting

I may still see Containers as a minimalistic VM like images on a Docker engine. (Docker noob)
But still, On VM's I host and run My web application on IIS, tomcat,... on port 80, 443, or whatever...
What does Docker use as a web hosting service ? nginx? how does it work anyway?

Comment: Docker docs explain perfectly how Docker works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is like a recipe. You take everything you need to run some code and you put it on a list. That list of ingredients is then able to be cooked anywhere that can run docker; where as a VM is like creating a new kitchen every time you need to run something. Because Docker is not creating a whole new instance of an OS, and is just running a layer above; the amount of time it takes to start a docker image is multitudes faster than a VM. This is a basic google search away, so in future it would be in your best interest to just look this up.